# How to get the content of a drop down list on page loading time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code gets the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

```
window.onload=function()
{
var selection = document.getElementById('connections');
var connectionName=selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text;
alert(connectionName);
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<select name="Connection" class="mdl-button" id="connections" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >    
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post what is on `connections`? or your html code?

Comment: <select name="Connection" class="mdl-button" id="connections" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >

Comment: Can you provide a full code

Comment: where did you set your selectionIndex?

Comment: I got this code from google.. its works fine when the call goes to myNewFunction(). But getting error when I put it inside window.onload()

Comment: Because "selectedIndex" is not found in your code

Comment: [edit] your post with your code.. please dont add as comment.

Comment: you might set the selectedIndex indside the myNewFunction , then you can get the selected option.  just give it a default value before :
    `var connectionName=selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Code like this

```
window.onload=function() {
   var selection = document.getElementById('connections');
   var connectionName=selection.options[selection.selectedIndex];
   if(connectionName) {
      alert(connectionName.text);
   }
 }
```

HTML Code Like this

```
<select name="Connection" class="mdl-button" id="connections" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
   <option value="a" selected> ram </option>
   <option value="b" >test </option>
</select>
```

Comment: options are added automatically from json response

Answer (score 0):

When the window `load` event is fired, your select doesn't contain any option.

So, `selection.selectedIndex` is valued to -1.

And so, `selection.options[selection.selectedIndex]` is undefined.

Comment: when the page loads select contains 2 options.

Comment: </div>
<select name="Connection" class="mdl-button" id="connections" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
<!-- <option ng-repeat="x in myData1 | unique: 'connectionId'" >{{x.connectionId}}</option> -->
  </select> 
                           </div>

Comment: var sel = document.getElementById('connections');//adds to drp dwn
for(var i = 0; i < connIds.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = connIds[i];
    opt.value = connIds[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}